# scp doesn't trigger initial prompt even though known_hosts is empty or deleted

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, scp, known-hosts

I have a bash script to copy a file to a remote server using `scp` and `expect`.  The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set file_to_send [lindex $argv 1]
set login [lindex $argv 2]@[lindex $argv 3]
set username [lindex $argv 2]
set hostname [lindex $argv 3]
set password [lindex $argv 4]
set dest_folder [lindex $argv 5]

spawn scp -P $port $file_to_send $login:$dest_folder
expect {
    # this will loop forever
    # {*fingerprint*}
    # sleep 0.8
    {Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/\[fingerprint\])?}
    {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    {password:} {send "$password\r"}    
}
expect eof
```

I want to get the initial prompt, given when my machine has never connected to the remote server.  Thus, I have tried both removing the added key inside `known_hosts` or that whole file in my machine.  However, I cannot get the initial prompt anymore.  This doesn't happen on another machine.  Either method gives me the initial prompt as expected.  Why is this happening?  What can I do to get what I want?

The outpout of `grep -i StrictHostKeyChecking ~/.ssh/config /etc/ssh/ssh_config` on all 3 machines is:

```
grep: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config: No such file or directory
/etc/ssh/ssh_config:#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
```

Comment: What is the OS? Assuming it's Linux, what is the output of `grep -i StrictHostKeyChecking ~/.ssh/config /etc/ssh/ssh_config`? Please [edit] the question and add information.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, done!

Comment: (1) `StrictHostKeyChecking` is commented out, but the default value is `ask` anyway. OK. (2) "I have tried both removing the added key inside `known_hosts` or that whole file in my machine." – Check `man 5 ssh_config`, [`GlobalKnownHostsFile`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#GlobalKnownHostsFile) and [`UserKnownHostsFile`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#UserKnownHostsFile). Not only one can use another file; one can use many files (the default setup uses four in total). So *maybe* you altered the wrong file or there is another file where information survived. Please investigate.

Comment: I figured it out!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit!  [UserKnownHostsFile](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#UserKnownHostsFile) default values are  `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and  `~/.ssh/known_hosts2`.  I renamed the original `known_hosts` into `known_hosts2` for comparison/debugging purpose.  Renaming it to `known_hosts3` triggers the initial prompt again.